# Why am I getting NAs in this calculation in R?

Tags: r, probability, missing-data

While working on an Rcpp program, I used the sample() function, which gave me the following error: "NAs not allowed in probability." I traced this issue to the fact that the probability vector I used had NA values in it. I have no idea how. Below is some R code that captures the errors:

```
n.0=20
n.1=20
n.reps=1
beta0.vals=rep(seq(-.3,.1,,n.0),n.reps)
beta1.vals=rep(seq(-7,0,,n.1),n.reps)
beta.grd=as.matrix(expand.grid(beta0.vals,beta1.vals))

n.rnd=200
beta.rnd.grd=cbind(runif(n.rnd,min(beta0.vals),max(beta0.vals)),runif(n.rnd,min(beta1.vals),max(beta1.vals)))
beta.grd=rbind(beta.grd,beta.rnd.grd)
  
N = 22670
count = 0

for(i in 1:dim(beta.grd)[1]){ # iterate through 600 possible beta values in beta grid
    
  beta.ind = 0 # indicator for current pair of beta values
    
  for(j in 1:N){ # iterate through all possible Nsums
    logit = beta.grd[i,1]/N*(j - .1*N)^2 + beta.grd[i,2];
    phi01 = exp(logit)/(1 + exp(logit))
      
    if(is.na(phi01)){ 
      count = count + 1
    }
  }
}

cat("Total number of invalid probabilities: ", count)
```

Here, $\beta_0 \in (-0.3, 0.1), \beta_1 \in (-7, 0), N = 22670, N_\text{sum} \in (1, N)$. Note that $N$ and $N_\text{sum}$ are integers, whereas the beta values may not be.

Since mathematically, $\phi_{01} \in (0,1)$, I'm assuming that NAs are arising because R is not liking extremely small values. I am receiving an overwhelming amount of NA values, too. More so than numbers. Why would I be getting NAs in this code?

Comment: A runnable example would help. Also, are the division and multiplication in the first line in the order that you intend?

Comment: This really belongs not here, but on stackoverflow, we can migrate it for you but first you need to make a reproducible (that is, runnable by just copying the code) example.

Comment: In the meantime, so that this thread does not collect misleading replies, it is best for it to be closed.  As soon as edits are made the community will get notice of that and can migrate it.  Alternatively, just post your question directly on [SO].  cc @Kjetil

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I added the reproducible code (in R, rather than Rcpp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bernhard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65876460/8386140) correctly identifies the problem:
If `logit` is large, `exp(logit) = Inf`.
Here is a solution:

```r
for(i in 1:dim(beta.grd)[1]){ # iterate through 600 possible beta values in beta grid
    
    beta.ind = 0 # indicator for current pair of beta values
    
    for(j in 1:N){ # iterate through all possible Nsums
        logit = beta.grd[i,1]/N*(j - .1*N)^2 + beta.grd[i,2];
        ## This one isn't great because exp(logit) can be very large
        # phi01 = exp(logit)/(1 + exp(logit))
        ## So, we say instead
        ## phi01 = 1 / ( 1 + exp(-logit) )
        phi01 = plogis(logit)
        
        
        if(is.na(phi01)){ 
            count = count + 1
        }
    }
}

cat("Total number of invalid probabilities: ", count)
# Total number of invalid probabilities:  0
```

We can use the more stable `1 / (1 + exp(-logit)`
(to convince yourself of this, multiply your expression with `exp(-logit) / exp(-logit)`),
and luckily either way, R has a builtin function `plogis()` that can calculate these probabilities quickly and accurately.
You can see from the help file (`?plogis`) that this function evaluates the expression I gave, but you can also double check to assure yourself

```r
x = rnorm(1000)
y = 1 / (1 + exp(-x))
z = plogis(x)
all.equal(y, z)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Very nice catch!

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have actually happened to have dealt with this exact issue much earlier in my statistical training in terms of (1) having the problem OP had, then (2) figuring out the more stable way to code the problem via math, then *much* later (3) realizing that of course R already had a built in function for it

Comment: The pertinent part here is _but of course R already had it covered_ ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Yep yep yep. 99 times out of a hundred, you twist yourself in knots and figure something out only to find out other devs (usually R Core) already solved your problem for you

Comment: I upvoted because this avoids `NA`. However, for values of `x` in the original poster's question, `1/(1+exp(-x))` will yield lots and lots of zeros as result as `1/Inf == 0`. Is not the information within a large number of zeros as small as that in a number of `NA`? The `NA` are there to tell you, that R could not compute what you wanted to be computed. The zeros might mislead you and prolong the time-to-error until you do further computation on the results.

Comment: @Bernhard I think you mean 1; OP is dealing with `logit` values of 746+, which would lead to 1, whereas values of -746 would lead to 0. Either way, in my opinion, having 0/1 rather than `NA` is preferable, as `1 / (1 + exp(-746)` is not meaningfully different from 1 for almost any practical application. `NA` would tell us we have no information, when the truth of the matter is that we do know that `phi01` is in actuality not meaningfully different from 1.

Comment: Yes, I should have meant 1.

Comment: Thank you to @duckmayr, Dirk, and Bernhard for contributing to my question. You have all been tremendously helpful in resolving this issue!

Comment: Happy to take credit but I didn't do much besides clapping from the sidelines while this still (wrongly, I mad add) had a `rcpp` tag.  Extra thanks to @JosephWood for cleaning that up too.

Answer (score 5):

Include `print(logit)` next to `count = count + 1` and you will find lots of logit > 1000 values. `exp(1000) == Inf`  so you divide `Inf` by `Inf` which will get you a `NaN` and `NaN` is `NA`:

```
> exp(500)
[1] 1.403592e+217
> Inf/Inf
[1] NaN
> is.na(NaN)
[1] TRUE
```

So your problems are not too small but to large numbers coming first out of the evaluation of `exp(x)` with `x` larger then roughly 700:

```
> exp(709)
[1] 8.218407e+307
> exp(710)
[1] Inf
```

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks for pointing that out. Is there I way that I can coerce exp(1000) to a double or something that will hold a value rather than Inf? Perhaps decreasing the size of N would also alleviate this issue, but I want N as large as possible.

Comment: `phi01 = exp(min(logit,709))/(1 + exp(min(logit,709)))` would do it unless you need `phi01`to avoid rounding to 0 or 1

Comment: @Henry Thanks for providing this quick trick!